# How is Laravel 8 CSRF token actually safe?

Tags: laravel, cookies, csrf

The most voted answer in this question (https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19128/csrf-cookie-vs-session-based-tokens) states

> If you put your token in a cookie, it will be send to the server automatically, just as session cookie, so you don't get any additional protection from that.

And Laravel seems to behave exactly as stated above. Here's the screenshot I have tested.

[image]

I am not sure whether I am doing some settings wrong or misunderstood about CSRF, but storing an extra CSRF cookie in addition to the session cookie really does not seem to be able to give any extra protection.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not always.
cookie with `SameSite` value of `None` will be always sent.
`XSRF-TOKEN` cookie has `SameSite=Lax` so it will be only sent at the same website.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite#none

> `SameSite=None` Cookies will be sent in all contexts, i.e. in responses to both
> first-party and cross-site requests. If SameSite=None is set, the
> cookie Secure attribute must also be set (or the cookie will be
> blocked).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite#lax

> `SameSite=Lax` Cookies are not sent on normal cross-site subrequests (for example to
> load images or frames into a third party site), but are sent when a
> user is navigating to the origin site (i.e., when following a link).

Comment: Based on my understanding, CSRF are basically bad requests that are hidden behind other links that the victim clicks, but are still sent "from a valid user (the victim)" "to the same/correct destination". Wouldn't this imply the `SamsSite` restriction is met as well?

Comment: @cr001 It will be sent only if the user is navigating with an anchor tag `a` or js redirection. They are `GET` requests and they shouldn't change any data. It prevents submitting a form which manipulates data. As far as I know Laravel CSRF protection doesn't protect `GET` requests so it doesn't effect anything if we send it or not.

Comment: Oh I see. That's actually the piece I am missing. The tutorial on CSRF uses GET requests as an example and I was confused. So if I make my site so that GET requests controllers never modify data I will be fine. Thank you so much.

Comment: Wait, but I still have the question that, why normal session cookies wouldn't achieve the same effect though? It looks like the local_session cookie in my test also has the LAX setting.

Comment: @cr001 Could you explain more.

Comment: There are two cookies sent by Laravel in the screenshot I posted in the question. One is the normal session cookie `local_session` and the other is the XSRF one. I am wondering wouldn't the session cookie itself already prevents POST request attacks?

Comment: @cr001 There shouldn't be any problems with that. It won't be sent when other websites request using Ajax or have a `img` with your link.

Comment: @cr001 Yes, if you use session authentication they won't pass any authorized route.

Comment: So when session authentication is used, then there is no need to enable the XSRF-Token. Am I correct or not?

Comment: @cr001 I guess but there might be something I'm missing. Like `iframes` or some advance usages.

Comment: I have tested the case with POST forms and it really seems there is a difference that normal session cookies do not achieve the effect that CSRF tokens does. I don't understand why though but thank you for your explanation anyway.